Test that plug is wired correctly
I am looking to build a tester that is verifying that 12 VDC connectors are wired for the correct polarity.  It will have a series of plugs for a wiring harness and a switch for each one with a red and green light.  If the harness is correct, the "Good" light will turn on for each connection, if not the "Reject" light will turn on for the wrong polarity plug(s).  I think I can just put a diode in series correct?  For this 12VDC tester I was thinking a diode like this one: https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Microchip-Technology/1N6006B?qs=TXMzd3F6EymO1SvtmfADhg%3D%3D ?
Please advise if this is what I should do.

What would be the use case for such a diode, if you want to light up a green or red light depending on polarity? Will you be using LEDs?

Originally, I was looking to use an industrial panel light which will work regardless of polarity.  I have found some automotive panel lights that are polarized that I think I'll use instead.



simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Figure 1. Test circuit.
How it works:

V1 powers the circuit.
R1 limits the current to 12 mA in the event of a short circuit.
D1, green, lights if polarity is correct.
D2, red, lights if polarity is reversed.

Component cost (excluding power supply): €0.50.

This won't detect a poor connection in a connector which would limit current.

@DoxyLover, contact / cable resistance testing isn't a user requirement.
